# Read .pgm in Julia v 1.0.1

Tags: load, julia, imread, pgm

How can i read/load .pgm file in julia. I am trying to read it through imread(".pgm") but compiler says that it only reads ".png" file.
Is there any other command for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Images.jl to read-in PGM file like this:

```
using Images
img = load("your_file_name.pgm")
```

Function `load` tries to infer the file type from its name and possibly magic bytes in the file so if your file has the `pgm` extension all should work fine.

Comment: I installed Pillow through Conda and then imread worked fine, as load asks for additional packages such as Netpbm,ImageMagick ...

Comment: :). Actually this pattern is useful in many cases where Python has a mature library ready as Julia-Python integration is simple and smooth (though I would say that the Images.jl is mature, but it is true that it has dependencies that have to be installed beforehand).